# Eigenfunctions of $x^2M''+xM'+\lambda M=0$ with $M'(1)=0$ and $M'(L)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

If we make the substitution of variables by $z=\ln(x)$ in $$x^2M''+xM'+\lambda M=0$$
then we will get
$$M''(z)=-\lambda M(z)$$
We can consider different cases for $\lambda$:

Case 1: $\lambda>0$

Solving and applying the boundary conditions, we get that no eigenfunctions exist in this case.

Case 2: $\lambda < 0$

Same as in Case 1.

Case 3: $\lambda = 0$

We get the constant function $M(x) = c_2$. But if we check the orthogonality condition (the weight function in this case is $\rho(x) = \frac{1}{x}$), we will not get $0$.

Where am I mistaken? I'd appreciate a clarification.

Comment: You need to recheck Case 1. The conclusion is wrong, there are solutions when $\lambda$ takes on specific values (something like $\lambda = Ak^2$ where $A$ is a constant depending on $L$ and $k$ is an integer) . For Case 2 there are no solutions unless $L=1$. Case 3 is correct.

Comment: Yes, it looks like I forgot about the constant $c_1$, thanks.

Comment: For Case 3, however, I'm wondering, if it's alright that the orthogonality condition for eigenfunctions is not satisfied?